# Error Installing composer with Homebrew

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew

I have just installed Composer on my mac OSX 10.12.1 using Homebrew:

```
brew install homebrew/php/composer
```

Then when I call

```
brew info homebrew/php/composer
```

It shows this:

```
homebrew/php/composer: stable 1.3.0 (bottled), HEAD
Dependency Manager for PHP
http://getcomposer.org
/usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.3.0 (5 files, 1.7M) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-01-08 at 16:33:31
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/composer.rb
==> Requirements
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Required: phpmeta ✔, phar ✔
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: why you want to use homebrew for composer installation ?

Comment: Well I've installed everything else via Homebrew: Apache, Mysql, PHP7.1, MongoDB, so I thought I'd keep everything together.

Comment: I just tried installing it the non-homebrew way as specified on the composer website and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an issue with your PHP installation.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0_11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mongodb.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

Check MongoDB extension. Maybe you've removed it, but the config still includes it (check all files in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/`).

Comment: I fixed it. It wasn't a composer issue, Trying to install Composer just alerted me to the problem. As you say it was a PHP configuration problem with mongodb. I fixed it by removing the mongodb extension from my PHP.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It wasn't a composer issue, Trying to install Composer just alerted me to the problem. As you say it was a PHP configuration problem with mongodb. I fixed it by removing the mongodb extension from my PHP.ini file.

Comment: Glad to see your issue was resolved. However, you answered your own question with this information, it is not the spot for comments. Instead, you should accept and upvote Alexey's answer, as it seems like it solved your problem. You could also leave this information as a comment on Alexey's answer for future visitors.